# Server capabilities - XMPP

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack

While using smack I am getting `"Client State Indication not supported by server".` I just wanted to know if server capabilities are likely to be changed with each connection. Example - If am using stream resumption , it is possible that sometimes connection doesn't support stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course features can change - servers can be upgraded or reconfigured. You'll have to be able to deal with this.

However, note that [XEP-0198](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html) stream resumption is not advertised using [XEP-0115 Entity Capabilities](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html), but as a stream feature. This means that the server always informs you whether it supports 0198 before you have to send the `<resume/>` and support for the feature can not change while you are connected.

Comment: Thanks for the details. For same user different session I am getting this issue with no server upgrade. Is it possible that the client is unable to fetch capabilities at the second go? I am not using entity cache and will be fixing it sometime in future.